# Pass a table variable from one stored procedure to another

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I'm working on a SQL Server 2005 database and I'm trying to pass a table variable from one stored procedure to another. Below is the structure of the table and my attempt.

@MyTable

```
EmployeeID    FirstName    LastName
1             Dummy        Last
2             Some         Name
```

I tried converting the table into XML and passing the XML as a parameter to the new SP.

```
SELECT * FROM @MyTable FOR XML AUTO
```

*Result*

```
<_x0040_MyTable EmployeeID="1" FirstName="Dummy" LastName="Last" />
<_x0040_MyTable EmployeeID="2" FirstName="Some" LastName="Name" />
```

But converting back from this XML to a table has become too complicated for my level of SQL knowledge. Am I on the right path? Is there an easy way?

Note - I have seen a few posts which suggests to use #temp tables and I would not prefer to use that solution. I would like to use the @MyTable parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Erland Sommarskog is your friend here. The link below provides a table showing options. For SQL Server 2005, TVF aren't an option. You will likely need to use XML or a temp table to share the data. I know you say these two are the least desirable options for you, but for 2005, I think they are the most appropriate.

http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html